# Static classes for variables instead of methods

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to store a number of unique variables (objects) in a class like so:

```
    //Notice that each object has unique attributes passed to it
    public static Entity SomeEntity01, SomeEntity02, SomeEntity03;

    SomeEntity01 = new Entity(some, values);
    SomeEntity02 = new Entity(some, new, values);
    SomeEntity03 = new Entity(some, other, values);
```

I wish to access these variables in the class like this:

```
MyClass.SomeEntity01
```

I can do this with instantiation, but it would obfuscate the code with useless instances. I can't do this ordinarily because classes don't allow object instantiation outside of methods (from what I can tell).

**If possible, how can I store and access variables (specifically objects) in a class without using instantiation or static methods?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize static fields in a static constructor:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static Entity SomeEntity01, SomeEntity02, SomeEntity03;

    static MyClass() // static constructor
    {
        SomeEntity01 = new Entity(some, values);
        SomeEntity02 = new Entity(some, new, values);
        SomeEntity03 = new Entity(some, other, values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah! I didn't even think a static constructor was possible. In the  context of OOP, it just seemed so absurd that I guess I never looked into it. Looking at it now on MSDN, I think I'll be more careful about my opinions. Thanks for helping me discover this.